# How to change an element.text in XML file using lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml.etree

Here an example of an xml file: Here the *houseNum* is not successive.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfHouse>
<XmlForm>
<houseNum>0</houseNum>
 <plan1> 
  <coord>
    <X> 1.2  </X>
    <Y> 2.1  </Y>
    <Z> 3.0  </Z>
  </coord>
  <color> 
    <R> 255 </R>
    <G> 0   </G>
    <B> 0   </B>
  </color>
 </plan1>
 <plan2>
  <coord>  
    <X> 21.2  </X>
    <Y> 22.1  </Y>
    <Z> 31.0  </Z>
  </coord>
  <color> 
    <R> 255 </R>
    <G> 0   </G>
    <B> 0   </B>
</color>
 </plan2> 
</XmlForm>

<XmlForm>
<houseNum>3</houseNum>
 <plan1> 
  <coord>
    <X> 1.2  </X>
    <Y> 2.1  </Y>
    <Z> 3.0  </Z>
  </coord>
  <color> 
    <R> 255 </R>
    <G> 0   </G>
    <B> 0   </B>
  </color>
 </plan1>
 <plan2>
  <coord>  
    <X> 21.2  </X>
    <Y> 22.1  </Y>
    <Z> 31.0  </Z>
  </coord>
  <color> 
    <R> 255 </R>
    <G> 0   </G>
    <B> 0   </B>
</color>
 </plan2> 
</XmlForm>

<XmlForm>
<houseNum>5</houseNum>
 <plan1> 
  <coord>
    <X> 11.2  </X>
    <Y> 12.1  </Y>
    <Z> 13.0  </Z>
  </coord>
  <color> 
    <R> 255 </R>
    <G> 255   </G>
    <B> 0   </B>
  </color>
 </plan1>
 <plan2>
  <coord>  
    <X> 211.2  </X>
    <Y> 212.1  </Y>
    <Z> 311.0  </Z>
  </coord>
  <color> 
    <R> 255 </R>
    <G> 0   </G>
    <B> 255   </B>
</color>
 </plan2> 
</XmlForm>
</ArrayOfHouse>
```

I want to modify the .text to be 0,1,3 instead of 0, 3, 5.Here is my script using lxml, that generates a false results.

```
def Rename_Elem_In_Xml_File(xml_file, index_start, index_end):
    # Parse from the xml string file
    tree = etree.parse(xml_file)
    #Rename the elements
    root = tree.getroot()
    elementlist = [e for e in root.iter('houseNum')]
    for index_element in range(1, len(elementlist)):
        try:
           if(index_element>index_start):
                elementlist[index_element].text=index_element
                print(elementlist[index_element].text)
        except:
            print(' except  ')
            print(elementlist[index_element].text)
    file = etree.tostring(root).decode("utf-8")
    print(file)
```

I try to iterate over the elements and change the text. This script delete the text and the beginning of the  tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting index_element to a string should fix the disappearing `<houseNum>` tag.

```
elementlist[index_element].text=str(index_element)
```

...

```
>>> rename.Rename_Elem_In_Xml_File('houses.xml', 0, 10)
1
2
<ArrayOfHouse>
<XmlForm>
<houseNum>0</houseNum>
 <plan1>
  <coord>
    <X> 1.2  </X>
    <Y> 2.1  </Y>
    <Z> 3.0  </Z>
  </coord>
  <color>
    <R> 255 </R>
    <G> 0   </G>
    <B> 0   </B>
  </color>
 </plan1>
 <plan2>
  <coord>
    <X> 21.2  </X>
    <Y> 22.1  </Y>
    <Z> 31.0  </Z>
  </coord>
  <color>
    <R> 255 </R>
    <G> 0   </G>
    <B> 0   </B>
</color>
 </plan2>
</XmlForm>

<XmlForm>
<houseNum>1</houseNum>
 <plan1>
  <coord>
    <X> 1.2  </X>
    <Y> 2.1  </Y>
    <Z> 3.0  </Z>
  </coord>
  <color>
    <R> 255 </R>
    <G> 0   </G>
    <B> 0   </B>
  </color>
 </plan1>
 <plan2>
  <coord>
    <X> 21.2  </X>
    <Y> 22.1  </Y>
    <Z> 31.0  </Z>
  </coord>
  <color>
    <R> 255 </R>
    <G> 0   </G>
    <B> 0   </B>
</color>
 </plan2>
</XmlForm>

<XmlForm>
<houseNum>2</houseNum>
 <plan1>
  <coord>
    <X> 11.2  </X>
    <Y> 12.1  </Y>
    <Z> 13.0  </Z>
  </coord>
  <color>
    <R> 255 </R>
    <G> 255   </G>
    <B> 0   </B>
  </color>
 </plan1>
 <plan2>
  <coord>
    <X> 211.2  </X>
    <Y> 212.1  </Y>
    <Z> 311.0  </Z>
  </coord>
  <color>
    <R> 255 </R>
    <G> 0   </G>
    <B> 255   </B>
</color>
 </plan2>
</XmlForm>
</ArrayOfHouse>
```